# ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Tags: mysql

I have recently migrated Mysql from 5.1 to 5.7 after that one specific query is ending up in error.
This is the query :

```
    select count(*) COUNT_PRODUCTS from 
 (select d.ID, d.EAN, d.NAME, d.SAP_CATEGORY_ID, d.SAP_VENDOR_ID, d.RELEASE_DATE,
 d.REMOVED_DATE, d.IS_DRAFT, d.DATA_STATE, d.gc, ATTRIBUTE_CODE AS ATTRIB_NAME, ATTRIBUTE_VALUE AS APP_STATUS from 
 (select b.ID, b.EAN, b.NAME,  b.SAP_CATEGORY_ID, b.SAP_VENDOR_ID, b.RELEASE_DATE, 
 b.REMOVED_DATE, b.IS_DRAFT, b.DATA_STATE,  group_concat(pl.LIFECYCLE_VALUE) gc from 
 (select a.ID, a.EAN, a.NAME,  a.SAP_CATEGORY_ID, a.SAP_VENDOR_ID, a.RELEASE_DATE, 
 a.REMOVED_DATE, a.IS_DRAFT, a.DATA_STATE  from 
 (select p.ID, p.EAN, p.NAME, p.SAP_CATEGORY_ID, p.SAP_VENDOR_ID, p.RELEASE_DATE, 
 p.REMOVED_DATE, p.IS_DRAFT,  p.DATA_STATE from PRODUCTS as p   order by p.EAN, p.IS_DRAFT) as a group by a.EAN )
 as b  left join PRODUCT_LIFECYCLE_STATES pl on pl.PRODUCT_ID = b.ID  group by b.ID ) as d left join PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_VALUES
 AS PRODAV ON ID=PRODAV.PRODUCT_ID AND PRODAV.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_ID IN
 (select ID from ATTRIBUTE_VALUES where ATTRIBUTE_CODE='APPROVED_ATTRIBUTES') 
 left join ATTRIBUTE_VALUES AS ATVALS ON PRODAV.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_ID = ATVALS.ID AND ATVALS.ATTRIBUTE_CODE ='APPROVED_ATTRIBUTES'
 ORDER BY d.SAP_CATEGORY_ID, d.NAME ) f
```

This is  the error I am receiving:

```
ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'a.ID' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

I have already tried changing SQL_MODE, but after changing query it isn't returning any output and its keep on loading.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Every column in the SELECT that is not an aggregate function (SUM(), AVG(), MIN(), MAX(), etc.) must also be in the GROUP BY statement. This is basic SQL. Also, posting a huge unformatted SQL mess with no effort to format it so that it's readable won't work out well for you. It's difficult to read a very long single line SQL statement (nearly 1200 characters!) where you have to scroll horizontally long distances. This site requires an [mcve], not a huge code dump.

Comment: What is your query doing?

Comment: @juergend , depending upon the filters it is providing the count of products.

Comment: If you provide example data and expected output we may come up with something way simpler

Answer (score 6):

You need to disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY

```
SET sql_mode = (SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', ''));
```

Comment: already tried that , result screen keeps on loading with no result.

Answer (score 2):

To solve the error, connect to the mysql server:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Execute a query that displays the values of sql_mode:

```
show variables like 'sql_mode';
```

At me it was displayed:

```
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Copy the string with these values, remove “ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY” and execute the query:

```
SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

By this request, we disabled “ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY” and after that the error will not be displayed.

Then we exit mysql:

```
exit
```

So that this error does not appear later, we need to open the MySQL configuration file. For example, in the text editor nano (Ctrl + X for exit, y/n for saving or canceling changes):

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

I did not have sql_mode= in the file, so at the end of the file I inserted the line with the previously copied values, removing from it ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, in my case, the following happened:

```
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Restart mysql to apply the changes:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Should be done ;).